# Webrtc Mix microphone output & mp3 into a single stream

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I am creating a webrtc based chat application.
(getUserMedia apis).

Trying to achieve this:

1)choose a mp3 file(local file OR web url) which is like a background music & sing a song.

2)The user at the other end should be able to hear both of these tracks (background music + my voice)

To achieve this, I am trying to merge two streams(mp3 stream + microphone) into a single stream & relay to another peer using webrtc peerconnection apis.
But am struck at merging two streams.

I followed this link https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/webrtc-integration.html but only microphone output is heard.

Any help/pointers on this please?

Comment: Putting two audio tracks in the same stream works in Firefox, but not Chrome yet. But it shouldn't matter, as you should be able to send two streams as well. Not sure what you mean by "merge" but I see no reason to combine the audio data here.

Comment: There should be no lag between the bg music & the voice, that's why am trying to combine both streams. If not imagine a case when bg music gets streamed faster than your voice, both of them would be out of sync.

Comment: I would try it and see if you get lag, as I don't see another option in Chrome atm. In Firefox you can combine tracks like this: `new MediaStream([streamA.getTracks()[0], streamB.getTracks()[0]]))`.